# authentication wordpress api

Tags: php, wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

i use this code for send image to wordpress by api

but i cant authentication wordpress api .

i use user name and password my user admin but show error 401 'rest_cannot_create'

my code :

```
<?php

$file = $_FILES["RESULT_FileUpload-6"]["tmp_name"];
$url = 'http://tst.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/';
$ch = curl_init();
$username = 'testuser1';
$password = '123456789';

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="'.$_FILES["RESULT_FileUpload-6"]["name"].'"',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ),
] );
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution which worked for me was to use this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/

From the terminal you can perform a POST as follows:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic ACCESS_TOKEN" -X POST -d "title=New Title" http://LOCALHOST/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/POST_ID}
```

I believe for that plugin you could probably write a method which fetches the access token from the database, I believe it is set in the options table...

Once you have managed to fetch it from the database, you can replace:

```
base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password )
```

With:

```
base64_encode( $access_token ),
```

Hope that helps!